# C++ Reading fstream data from a file does not return correct values. inputFile.tellg returns -1

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ifstream, file-pointer

I am trying to read data from an input file that contains an integer on the first line ( represents the number of images listed in the file ), a float on the second line( this is used for other calculations within the main program ) and float values on each subsequent line that end with a name of an image file all in the same data.txt file.  The last line of the data.txt file contains a brief description of what the data is used for but is not read by the program. 
When I try to read the data and print it out to the screen the values are incorrect. 
The first line of the data.txt file is a 5 but when I print it out I get a 0 which is what I initialized it to.  The second line is a float value I believe and that is also output as a 0 which is what it is initialized to also.
The rest of the data is read in by a while loop with only parts of the data being printed out but nothing prints.
I inserted a cout << inputFile.tellg << endl; statement to see where the file pointer is pointing to but it is returning -1.
I am totally stuck on this.  Any insight would greatly be appreciated.
Thank you for your time and expertise.

Please find attached a sample copy of the data.txt file as well as the main.cpp file.

**data.txt**

```
5
5.50e+11
 4.4960e+11  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  4.9800e+04  5.9740e+24       cat.gif
 3.2790e+11  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  3.4100e+04  6.4190e+23       dog.gif
 2.7900e+10  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  7.7900e+04  3.3020e+23     mouse.gif
 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  6.0000e+00  1.9890e+30  squirrel.gif
 5.0820e+11  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  7.5000e+04  4.8690e+24       fox.gif

This file contains an example of data stored in a text file
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] )
{
      float xPosition, yPosition;
      float xVelocity, yVelocity;
      float animalMass;
      string imgFilename;
      string line;
      istringstream inputStream( line );
      auto N = 0;   // Number of items
      auto R = 0; // Real number from file

  cout << "begin" << endl;
  if( argc > 1 )
  {
    string fileName = argv[ 1 ];
    ifstream inputFile( fileName );
    inputFile.open( fileName, ios::in );

    if( !inputFile.is_open( ))
    {
      cout << setw( 5 ) << " " << "Could not open file " << fileName << "." << endl;
      cout << setw( 5 ) << " " << "Terminating program." << endl;
      exit( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
      cout << inputFile.tellg() << endl;
      inputFile >> N;
      inputFile >> R;
      cout << "N is now " << N << endl;
      cout << "R is now " << R << endl;
      cout << inputFile.tellg() << endl;

      while( inputFile >> xPosition >> yPosition
                       >> xVelocity >> yVelocity
                       >> animalMass   >> imgFilename )
      {
        cout << xPosition << " " << imgFilename << endl;
      }       
    }
  } 
}
```

**OUTPUT as follows:**

os:~/Desktop/test$ ./main data.txt

begin

-1

N is now 0

R is now 0

-1

---

At a minimum I would expect N to be 5 since I may have the type wrong for
R or maybe more calculations are required once the data is read, I am not sure.
I just don't get why the file pointer is showing it is at location -1.

Comment: try removing `inputFile.open( fileName, ios::in );` because the previous line already opened the file. Also, declare `float R = 0` instead of `auto R = 0`.

Comment: It works. This was exactly the problem.  I removed inputFile.open( fileName, ios::in ) and declared R as float instead of auto.  Thank you very much.  I am not sure why the previous statement opened the file.  I thought it was necessary to explicitly call inputFile.open( fileName, ios::in ) to open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by the declaration of `R`.

```
auto R = 0;
```

The above declaration makes `R` an `int`, not a `double` or `float`.

Use

```
double R = 0;
```

You could use

```
auto R = 0.0;
```

but I don't recommend it. Use of `auto` makes sense when the type is long winded and cumbersome to type. For simple types, as above, it is better to be explicit.

If you need to use `float` for `R`, use

```
float R = 0;
```